# Radare2 Load file from stdin fails

Tags: radare2

Radare2 supports loading a file from stdin via `=`.  However, my attempts to use it don't work:

```
$ r2 /bin/ls
Warning: run r2 with -e bin.cache=true to fix relocations in disassembly
[0x00006810]> q
$ cat /bin/ls | r2 =
^D
[0x00000000]> q
               $
```

Note only does it not work, as shown above, but I need to `reset` my term afterwards!

Comment: please feel free to submit the issue at https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/

Comment: also, you can join DIscord server or Telegram group -- you will get faster responses